# passing parameters to a view ms crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I've custom view on account entity and I want to pass parameters dynamically to that view. When I try to pass parameters as below i got an error. Is there any best way to pass parameter to a view like individual records.

[http://mycrm/myorg/main.aspx?etc=1&extraqs=address1_postalcode%3DCB4&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b12EC908C-44CB-E111-911F-F04DA2F5F23E%7d&viewtype=4230]

any suggestions

Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that passing dynamically parameters to view is not possible. In this situation you can use advanced find, filters, or create report.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar requirement: We have a ribbon button, click the button popup a silverlight page, this is a search screen, you can input the search criteria and click search button on that page. The search result will be returned to CRM Home page.(Not the advanced find, it returns the results to CRM home page).

Actually, what we have to do is create the QueryExpression from silverlight, and then convert it to fetch xml query, use this fetch xml query to create a custom view, attach the custom view to home page.